# Dynamically change Google Maps icon by type in array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am completely new to javascript and have been tasked with converting an old jvector map to the google maps API. I think i'm doing pretty well so far! I've managed to get the map to populate with all the right markers in all the assigned spots, with nice shiny infowindows popping up when they're clicked. That part is fine so far.

Where i'm having trouble is when I am trying to dynamically change google maps icons on map load, based on whether a string from an array matches a list of 8 different types. The main code i'm working with looks like:

### Data array sample

The array has roughly 30 stories however for brevity I've removed the content and provided the code structure below.

```
 var stories = [
    // ACT Markers 
    // ACT ICT
    {
        latlng: [-35.3449476, 148],
        name: "Business name - tagline after the business name",
        type: "ICT",
        text: 'some basic text marked up with html',
           },
```

### Main code sample:

```
window.onload = function() {
    LoadMap();
};

function LoadMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-content"), mapOptions);

    for (var i = 0; i < stories.length; i++) {
        var storydata = stories[i];
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(storydata.latlng[0], storydata.latlng[1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: storydata.name,
            content: storydata.text,
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this.title + this.content);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
```

So far all this works fine. There is very likely a smarter or more efficient way to do this but as I said i'm completely new to javascript of any kind.

### Categorisation: The Problem

What i'd now like to do is change the icon based on the stories.type. 
I've been playing around with the following based on some other stackoverflow threads (can't seem to find the links) but I have no idea where to insert the code to make it work or if i'm even really in the right ball park.

```
for (var item in stories) {
    if (stories[i].type == 'Agrifood') iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
    else if (stories[i].type == 'Biotechnology') iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/pink-dot.png';
    else if (stories[i].type == 'BuiltEnvironment') iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
    else if (stories[i].type == 'Energy') iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png';
    else if (stories[i].type == 'Engineering') iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png';
    else if (stories[i].type == 'ICT') iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/ltblue-dot.png';
    else if (stories[i].type == 'Manufacturing') iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png';
    else if (stories[i].type == 'Mining') iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
    else iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
}
```

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You should add these iconString to your markers property icon befor adding them to the map. Take a look to custom marker https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify a little bit your code, this should do the trick:

```
for (var i = 0; i < stories.length; i++) {
    var storydata = stories[i];
    var iconString = '';
    switch (storydata.type) {
        case 'Agrifood':
            iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
            break;
        case 'Biotechnology':
            iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/pink-dot.png';
            break;
        case 'BuiltEnvironment':
            iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png';
            break;
        case 'Energy':
            iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png';
            break
        case 'Engineering':
            iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png';
            break;
        case 'ICT':
            iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/ltblue-dot.png';
            break;
        case 'Manufacturing':
            iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/orange-dot.png';
            break;
        case 'Mining':
            iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
            break;
        default:
            iconString = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
    }

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(storydata.latlng[0], storydata.latlng[1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: iconString,
        title: storydata.name,
        content: storydata.text
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(this.title + this.content);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```