# How to write if condition in google map function? How to dynamically change image?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to change the image in google map based on the dynamic values

if `value === 1`, it should be `1.jpg` , if `value === 2` it should be `2.jpg` like that. I need to change the images based on the JSON data coming from data base. 3 images empty bin, normal bin , full bin

```
 <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCLi6l" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script>

var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(22.8046, 86.2029);
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:14,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var image = 1;
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  icon:'img/dustbin3.png'
});


marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:1580px;height:780px;"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: so where the images supposed to be displayed ?? could clarify more please

Comment: i want to show one dustbin at one particular longitude and latitude. according to values i want to change differnert images. full dustbin, empty dustbin, etc. i updated my question

Comment: Yes googles api can work with conditionals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860677/dynamically-change-google-maps-icon-by-type-in-array-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure if it't the right thing wjat you're looking for but i can suggest you to try this one

```
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var value = //result of your JSON data
var v_icon='';

if(value<50){
   v_icon = '1.jpg';
}else if(value>50 && value<90){
   v_icon = '2.jpg';
}else if(value>90){
   v_icon = '3.jpg';
}

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  icon: v_icon
});
```

if it is not that so i didn't understood well what are you trying to achieve :)

Comment: it's already given in your "myCenter" variable !! so the Marker will be set on LatLng(22.8046, 86.2029)

Comment: i have value from 1 to 100, if its value <50... 1.jpg, if value greater than 50 and less than 90..2.jpg and if value more than 90 ..it should be 3.jpg

Comment: it will work with the same logic with an if-else but from where you are getting that value ??

Comment: im getting the value from json data.

Comment: @sanjay you can check my edit now let me know if it work or not